# passing data to a new scree nusing builder (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm tryng to pass data from grid view builder to a materialpageroute component to a new screen, I already pass movies index, but can't seem to give it to the new screen

[image: grid builder]

[image: new page handler]

Comment: You are passing a single Movie into the `DetailPage`, but waiting for a `List<Movie>`.  Also, in AppBar you are passing the `Title(String)` object instead of the `title: Text(String)`.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to pass a single `Movie` object into your widget but not a list and index.

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, you are trying to assign `title` as a parameter in `onTap` function. You cannot do that in `onTap`.

I think you want to pass the title to `DetailPage`, you can get the `title` in `movies[index]`, so you don't have to declare a title.

In the second screenshot, if you want to show the title of your movie in the `AppBar`, you must do it using `title` parameter.

```
AppBar(
  title: Text(movies[index].original_title),
),
```

And you cannot give just one widget to `Column`'s `children` parameter. It must be a list.

```
Column(
  children: [
    _yourWidget(),
  ],
), // put your widget inside list
```

If you have one widget, you don't need to use `Column`.

Lastly, you get just one `movie`, so that you don't have to use `ListView`. You can use a single widget like `Container`. And if you want your view can be scrollable, you can wrap the `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`, like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      _yourWidget(),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Edit: You didn't declare movies at the top:

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Movie? movies; // declare this first
  const DetailPage {...} // your constructor
}
```

Comment: i got unidentified index, is that because I don't use builder?

Comment: In ListView.builder, you need to give the length of the list in itemCount parameter.